# Errors appear in searching if a record not found using searchtext

Tags: php, search

SearchText works if record is found but errors appear when record not found.
Here are the errors. Notice: Undefined variable: sample_list in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewsample\samplelist.php on line 166
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ viewsample\samplelist.php on line 166
If I click the search button again,  errors disappear.
Is it possible to return to home page if record not found?
I searched here  a possible solution to my problem but I found none.

Please help.
Thank you and more power.

Here's  the code.
       **Index.php**

```
//Perform Search from our database  
    if(isset($_POST['action_type']))                  
    {           
      echo 'Welcome';  
      if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'search')  
        {  
          $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['searchText']));     
            $sql = "select samp_id, daterecv, datecoll, modcoll, aperson, estabname, estabadd, gname, bname, prodcat, dform, dstrength, from sample 
            where gname like '%$search%' or bname like '%$search%' or estabname like '%$search%'";  
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);    
              if(!$result)
              {  
                echo mysqli_error($link);  
                exit();
             }  

        //Loop through each row on array and store the data to $sample_list[]
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $sample_list[] = array('samp_id' => $rows['samp_id'],
                                        'daterecv' => $rows['daterecv'],
                                        'datecoll' => $rows['datecoll'],
                                        'modcoll' => $rows['modcoll'],
                                        'apers' => $rows['apers'],
                                        'estabname' => $rows['estabname'],
                                        'estabadd' => $rows['estabadd'],
                                        'gname' => $rows['gname'],
                                        'bname' => $rows['bname'],
                                        'prodcat' => $rows['prodcat'],
                                        'dform' => $rows['dform'],
                                        'dstrength' => $rows['dstrength']);
        }
            include 'samplelist.php';
            exit();
       }
   }
```

**samplelist.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
    $role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) && $role!="sampler"){
      header('Location: index.php?err=2');
    }
?>
<?php 
include_once 'index.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function GotoHome(){
    window.location = 'index.php';
}
{
function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
  setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
  window.onunload=function(){null};
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="content">
            <p><a href="../logout.php" class="link-btn">Logout</a></p>
            <p><center><b><font style="arial" color="black">SAMPLE COLLECTION</font></b></center></p>
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <form method="POST" action="index.php">
                <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" style="width:300px"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="search" onfocus="Clear (this);"/>
                <input type="submit" value="search"/>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div style="max-height: 740px; overflow:auto; max-width: 1600; overflow:auto;">
            <table class="pbtable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Date Received
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Date Collected
                        </th>
                        <th style = "display:none">
                            Mode of Collection
                        </th>
                        <th style = "display:none">
                            Assigned Personnel
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Establishment Name
                        </th>
                        <th style = "display:none">
                            Establishment Address
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Generic Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Brand Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product Category
                        </th>
                        <th style = "display:none">
                            Dosage Form
                        </th>
                        <th style = "display:none">
                            Dosage Strength
                         </th>
</thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($sample_list as $collection) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $collection["daterecv"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $collection["datecoll"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td style = "display:none">
                                <?php echo $collection["modcoll"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td style = "display:none">
                                <?php echo $collection["aperson"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $collection["estabname"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td style = "display:none">
                                <?php echo $collection["estabadd"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $collection["gname"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $collection["bname"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $collection["prodcat"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td style = "display:none">
                                <?php echo $collection["dform"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td style = "display:none">
                                <?php echo $collection["dstrength"]; ?>
                            </td>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="ci" 
            value="<?php echo $collection["samp_id"]; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </form> 
            <tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If no records are found in DB the $sample_list array is empty.
So samplelist.php needs this check before foreach loop,

```
if (empty($sample_list)) 
{
    header('Location: http://www.homesweet.home/');
    exit;
}

foreach($sample_list as $collection) : 
    ...
endforeach;
```